# Can you "fork" a VS Code extension or make extensions work together?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I recently found out that VS Code has a beautiful Hex Editor extension made by Microsoft, but the problem is that it doesn't support adding tags / markers to HEX, which is a pretty common feature for such tools, and my workflow relies on using it. I haven't really found any info on this in the docs, but maybe I am just not that good at searching.

So my question is: is there a way to either make my own "fork" of the Microsoft extension or make a separate extension that adds the aforementioned feature to the editor provided by it?

Comment: yes you can fork the repo and make the modifications and use it only on your PC but you can also make a pull-request and maybe they integrate it in the HexEditor extension and we all benefit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-hexeditor) is the Github repository for the extension. You can fork it like any open source project.

To edit the extension, you will need to install Node.js and npm on your computer, then run `npm i` and `npm run watch` from the root of the project.

Once you are done, you can do `vsce package` to package the extension and use it with VSCode.

Note that this extension is open source, meaning you can open a pull-request if you think other people might benefit from them.

Comment: Alternatively, he can publish it under the same (or a compatible) license as new work, with an own author ID. But a PR is certainly the better solution.

Comment: `npm install -g @vscode/vsce` to install the extension management tool. More info here https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#packaging-extensions